# Can I link a beer brand or specific model or should I be generic?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked [this question](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4533/techniques-to-add-flavour-and-aroma-to-beer-with-hops), Is caused because an specific technique **bottle dry-hopping** I've found Naparbier (Spain) brewers are using and I've never seen before.

- Is ok to name / link the beer and it's brewer? 
   *The question is related to it's production process, I don't know any other example and will help others if any one want to taste it*
- Or should I be generic?
  *This may be seen as Spam or promotion of the brand*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would say that's fine, because it's pertinent to the question.  Spam is only a concern when the reference is purely for promotional purposes, and particularly when there is an undisclosed relationship between you and the product that you're mentioning.

If you look through our existing questions and answers, brands and specific beers are commonly mentioned, so we've clearly set precedent that by itself, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

By own experience, I can tell you I have done it here a few times and haven't heard from anyone to not to do that. I don't see any problem as well. Many times, it's almost impossible to ask or answer something without mentioning brands. Don't be afraid.